# Multiple URLs in proxy

Tags: extjs4

How can I use multiple URLs in a proxy in Extjs 4?

```
Proxy:{
        url:'?'
      }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

storename.getProxy().url='your-url'

Answer (score 1):

in your store:

```
proxy: {        
      type: 'ajax',
      api: {
       read: '/controller/read',
       update: '/controller/update',
       create: '/controller/create'
     },
    ....
```